# Como posso somar horários ditos pelo usuário?

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime

inicio = input(
    'Informe o horario de inicio do experimento (formato Horas:Minutos:Segundos): ')
termino = input(
    'Quanto tempo durara o experimento (formato Horas:Minutos:Segundos): ')

convert_inicio = inicio.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
convert_termino = termino.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
soma_horario = convert_inicio + convert_termino

print(soma_horario)
```

Estou usando o código descrito acima, mas está dando este erro:

[image: Esse é o erro que vem causando.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, existem dois conceitos importantes que você deve saber para entender como resolver o seu problema: "horários" e "durações". Para entender melhor, considere as duas frases abaixo:

- o filme começa às duas horas da tarde
- o filme tem duração de duas horas

No primeiro caso, "duas horas" refere-se a um horário: a um momento específico do dia.

No segundo caso, "duas horas" refere-se a uma duração: a uma quantidade de tempo. Nesse caso, ela não diz quando o filme começa ou termina (nem se ele foi de fato exibido). Ela só diz a duração (quanto tempo ele dura), sem qualquer relação com algum horário específico.

O problema é que usamos as mesmas palavras (horas, minutos, etc) para ambos, mas eles são conceitos diferentes. Para piorar, até mesmo a forma de escrever pode ser igual: por exemplo, muitos cronômetros mostram `02:00` para indicar uma duração de duas horas, igual a um relógio.

Apesar de diferentes, estes conceitos estão relacionados. Se você somar uma data e uma duração, o resultado é outra data (se eu sei o horário que algo começa e quanto tempo dura, consigo calcular a hora que termina).

Em Python, uma duração é representada por [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), enquanto datas e horas são representadas por [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects).

---

Além disso, você está confundindo o horário com a representação do horário. [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) retorna uma string (um texto), e um texto não é um `datetime`. Por exemplo, "10:00" e "10 horas" são textos diferentes, mas ambos representam o mesmo horário (são strings diferentes que representariam o mesmo `datetime`).

Sendo assim, você precisa gerar estes objetos (converter as strings para `datetime` e `timedelta`) antes de somá-los.

Ou seja, você precisa transformar a primeira string em data, usando [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) em vez de [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) (repare no "p" em vez de "f" no nome - isso porque  ***p**arsing* é o processo de transformar uma string em uma data, e **f**ormatação é o processo oposto).

Já a segunda string na verdade deve ser convertida para `timedelta`, pois ela representa uma duração. Infelizmente, não há uma forma direta de fazer o *parsing*, então você deve fazê-lo manualmente:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

inicio = input('Informe o horario de inicio do experimento (formato Horas:Minutos:Segundos): ')
data_inicio = datetime.strptime(inicio, "%H:%M:%S") # transforma a string em data

duracao = input('Quanto tempo durara o experimento (formato Horas:Minutos:Segundos): ')
horas, minutos, segundos = map(int, duracao.split(':'))
# transforma a string em timedelta
duracao = timedelta(hours=horas, minutes=minutos, seconds=segundos)

# soma a data à duração
termino = data_inicio + duracao

# formata o resultado
print(termino.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Repare que só usei `strftime` no final, para formatar o `datetime` (ou seja, para transformá-la em uma string em um formato específico).

---

O código não valida se o que foi digitado está no formato correto (se não estiver, dará erro).

Se quiser, você pode fazer um *loop* que pede para o usuário digitar novamente caso o dado seja inválido:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

while True:
    try:
        inicio = input('Informe o horario de inicio do experimento (formato Horas:Minutos:Segundos): ')
        data_inicio = datetime.strptime(inicio, "%H:%M:%S")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Não foi digitada uma data válida no formato hh:mm:ss')

while True:
    try:
        duracao = input('Quanto tempo durara o experimento (formato Horas:Minutos:Segundos): ')
        horas, minutos, segundos = map(int, duracao.split(':'))
        duracao = timedelta(hours=horas, minutes=minutos, seconds=segundos)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Não foi digitada uma duração no formato hh:mm:ss')

termino = data_inicio + duracao
print(termino.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```