# Como somar tempos em python

Tags: python, soma

Como posso somar, por exemplo: 1:12:34 + 0:18:53 + 0:0:50

O resultado precisa ser 1:32:17

Comment: Não é exatamente igual, mas dá pra ter uma ideia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466629/112052 (resumindo, transforme todos os valores em `timedelta` e some-os)

Comment: @hkotsubo me parece igual, só que a "linkada" é mais "complementar" (devido a boa resposta), ou seja, cobre todos os pontos e ainda por cima dá explicações extras, que é a parte de duração x horarios (que é inclusive o que a pergunta aqui deixou ambíguo)

Answer (score -1):

O tempo seria uma string nesse caso correto? Então o que você precisa fazer é manipular ela recortando-a, por exemplo:

```
a = '1:12:34'
b = '0:18:53'
c = '0:00:50'
if a[1] != ':': #checando se a hora tem 1 ou 2 carácteres
    ah = int(a[0])
    '''Separando a hora caso o segundo digito seja diferente de 0, lembre-se: o valor inicial é 0'''
    am = int(a[2:4])
    as = int(a[5:]) #ou seja, daqui até a string acabar
else:
    ah = int(a[0:2])
    am = int(a[3:5])
    ass = int(a[6:])
```

Ótimo! Agora precisamos transformar as horas e os minutos em segundos, até porque na escola você fazia/faz a transformação e depois somava correto? Então:

```
ahs = ah*3600
ams = am*60
astotal = ams + ahs + ass
```

Agora é só replicar esses passos com o b e o c, mas claro, utilizando variáveis diferentes (no meu caso irei substituir o “a” inicial por b e c:

```
if b[1] != ':':
    bh = int(b[0])
    bm = int(b[2:4])
    bs = int(b[5:]) #ou seja, daqui até a string acabar
else:
    bh = int(b[0:2])
    bm = int(b[3:5])
    bs = int(b[6:])

if c[1] != ':':
    ch = int(c[0])
    cm = int(c[2:4])
    cs = int(c[5:]) #ou seja, daqui até a string acabar
else:
    ch = int(c[0:2])
    cm = int(c[3:5])
    cs = int(c[6:])

bhs = bh*3600
bms = bm*60
bstotal = bms + bhs + bs

chs = ch*3600
cms = cm*60
cstotal = cms + chs + cs
```

Agora só precisamos somá-las:

```
stotal = astotal + bstotal + cstotal
```

Após essas etapas poderemos finalmente transformá-las em horas e minutos, mas temos um problema: e se o minuto ou segundo for 00? Ao transformar as strings agora separadas precisamos saber o que irá acontecer com ele. Então, ele será transformado em apenas um 0, e não queremos que o horário fique por exemplo “1:0:0” correto? Então iremos fazer o seguinte:

```
h = str(stotal//3600) #divisão inteira para segundos virarem horas
stotalm = stotal - h*3600
m = stotalm//60
if m == 0:
    m == '00'
else:
    m == str(m)
s = stotalm - m*60
if s == 0:
    s == '00'
else:
    s = str(s)
```

Agora é só juntar:

-Para Python 3.6+

```
total = f'{h}:{m}:{s}'
```

-Para Python 3

```
total = '{}:{}:{}'.format(h, m, s)
```

Pronto! Qualquer erro na execução do código por favor comente.

Comment: Editei a resposta, para obter as respostas mais recentes, por favor atualize a página por garantia

Comment: Atualizei a resposta novamente, poderia tentar novamente por favor?